# Is it possible to connect two RoR 5 websites to one amazon RDS DB with monthly costs

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

As stated above I want to configure two webapps hosted on heroku w/ one amazon RDS DB instance, e. g. via table_prefixes or `database.yml`.

Can somebody please give advice on how to do that and if it is possible at all?

Thanks!

Comment: you'll probably want to create two databases, two users with different permissions, then they can both write to their own database.  The apps don't need to know or care about each other.  Where are you having issues?

Comment: I have the issue that two databases cost two time monthly fee!

Comment: You pay per server, not per database  You can put many databases and users on one server.

Comment: OK! Just "create database" and I am done?

Comment: I will try to create a DB on a small server instance: though the calculator gives two times DB costs here: https://calculator.aws/#/estimate?id=b1c682afc21a383e657218bed32604bf5643042a

Comment: I have no AWS server, what is the product name for it? I have free tier DB instance like this:
db.t2.micro
1 vCPUs
1 GiB RAM
20 GiB
0.024 USD/hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create as many databases as you like on one one  db.t2.micro RDS instance .  just "CREATE DATABASE blah" as the admin user, create a new user for the new database and grant access.  RDS doesn't care if you use a database for one app or for 1000 apps.  You may run out of connection slots or other resources, but from a data perspective, these applications can be completely isolated through permissions and still share a single RDS server.

Comment: When I click "create database" in RDS console, then it suggests me a new dB.t2.micro instance w/ free tier and monthly costs!

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_db.asp Databases are also a concept within an existing database server.   This is something that can be created inside a database server by connecting with an sql client and issuing a CREATE DATABASE command.  You don't do it through the amazon web UI.

Comment: OK: here we go - I installed SQuirreL and got the same error as in my Rails 5 app:

    Unexpected Error occurred attempting to open an 
    SQL connection.
    class java.net.UnknownHostException: 
    cyo1f7mucyku.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com: 
    Name or service not known

Comment: that doesn't look like a complete name to me.  But you're really beyond the scope of your question here.  If you don't know how to connect to an RDS instance and sort out all the networking there, you should ask a question  regarding that, probabably on the SuperUser site

Comment: I understand explanation, but you have to tell me...
Follow up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61560947/error-connecting-rails-5-app-database-yml-to-aws-rds-instance