# Error connecting Rails 5 app database.yml to AWS RDS instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku

I already set up SLL certificate like here:

```
export DATABASE_URL="mysql2://leder:password@pfhpdb.cyo1f7mucyku.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com/pfhpdb?sslca=config/amazon-rds-ca-cert.pem"
```

when running my heroku rails 5 app w/ production environment and DB I get the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Can't connect to MySQL server on 'pfhpdb.cyo1f7mucyku.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (101 "Network is unreachable")):
```

My `database.yml` is as follows:

```
production:
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
host: pfhpdb.cyo1f7mucyku.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com
database: pfhpdb
pool: 5
username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Comment: same error when connecting to RDS w/ SQuirreL - `class java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable (connect failed)`!

**UPDATE 20200503:**
as of this post:
[Mariadb connection client: Access denied for user (using password: NO) on mysql 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54188309/mariadb-connection-client-access-denied-for-user-using-password-no-on-mysql)

I cannot login w/ password in MariaDB and cannot change DB table access b/c I cannot login w/ password in MariaDB. I am shut off from my DB...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the authentication error went away by resetting the AWS RDS DB administrator password in the console settings of RDS.

Answer (score 1):

Please check security group of your RDS instance; probably you have not opened the port. Also, please try this to see if port is open or not.

```
$ telnet cyo1f7mucyku.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com 3306
```

Comment: security group: `All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0`
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable

Comment: How can the port be closed if I allow all the inbound traffic!?

Comment: yes if u have allowed all inbound ; we are good. can u try to connect to your rds using some mysql client like workbench.. so that u will be sure its not RAILS issue but RDS issue.

Comment: I added an update connecting w/ SQuirreL and error `class java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user`

Comment: access denied for user means that it could connect to database while Rails was not able to even connect to DB !